# How to capture a whole painting when its scrolled out in flutter custom paint

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter, flutter-custompaint

This is the code - I implemented a custom paint widget to draw a drawing, but when I scroll the things up or down, the painting which is go outside of the screen is not captured.

I work for this thing from very long time but I am unable to do it by myself.

[Image of the drawing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfqnK.jpg)

[image of pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvYy1.jpg)

Please can someone help me to figure this out?

```
Future<void> captureAndSaveImage(
    {ui.PictureRecorder? recorder, GlobalKey? repaintKey}) async {
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      repaintKey!.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 10.0);
  ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List uint8List = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

  print(byteData);
  final pdf = pdf_widgets.Document();
  //Request permissions if not already granted
  if (!(await Permission.storage.status.isGranted))
    await Permission.storage.request();

  pdf.addPage(
    pdf_widgets.Page(
      // pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a3,
      build: (pdf_widgets.Context context) {
        return pdf_widgets.Image(
          pdf_widgets.MemoryImage(uint8List),
        );
      },
    ),
  );

  //get the date to set name of the file
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime date =
      DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second);

  final directory = await getDownloadsDirectory();
  final file = File('${directory!.path}/${date.toString()}.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

  print('File saved to ${file.path}');
}


enum CanvasState { draw, panUpdate }

class PaintPrescription extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaintPrescription({super.key});
  static String id = 'paintPrescription';

  @override
  State<PaintPrescription> createState() => _PaintPrescriptionState();
}

class _PaintPrescriptionState extends State<PaintPrescription> {
  List<List<Offset>> points = [];
  List<List<Offset>> redoStack = [];
  List<Offset> currentPath = [];
  Offset offset = Offset(0, 0);
  CanvasState canvasState = CanvasState.draw;
  final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  final GlobalKey _repaintKey = GlobalKey();
  late Canvas canvas;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    canvas = Canvas(recorder);
  }

  void _changeMode() {
    setState(() {
      canvasState = (canvasState == CanvasState.draw)
          ? CanvasState.panUpdate
          : CanvasState.draw;
    });
  }

  Widget _appBarButtons(
      {required void onPressed(), required IconData iconData}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: IconButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          icon: Icon(
            iconData,
            size: 27.0,
            color: kAppBlue,
          )),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext coheightntext) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        actions: [
          _appBarButtons(onPressed: _undo, iconData: Icons.undo_rounded),
          _appBarButtons(onPressed: _redo, iconData: Icons.redo_rounded),
          _appBarButtons(
              onPressed: _changeMode,
              iconData: canvasState == CanvasState.panUpdate
                  ? Icons.swipe_vertical_rounded
                  : Icons.swipe_vertical_outlined)
        ],
      ),

      //body
      body: GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: (details) => _startPath(details.localFocalPoint),
        onScaleUpdate: (details) {
          if (canvasState == CanvasState.panUpdate)
            _updatePan(details.focalPointDelta);
          else
            _updatePath(details.localFocalPoint);
        },
        onScaleEnd: (_) => _endPath(),
        child: RepaintBoundary(
          key: _repaintKey,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: PrescriptionWritter(points, offset),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      //send button
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () =>
            captureAndSaveImage(recorder: recorder, repaintKey: _repaintKey),
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        child: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PrescriptionWritter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<List<Offset>> points;
  Offset offset;

  PrescriptionWritter(this.points, this.offset);
  var currentPaint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..strokeWidth = 3.0;

  @override
  void paint(canvas, Size size) {
    for (final path in points) {
      for (int i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        if (path[i] != Offset(-1, -1) && path[i + 1] != Offset(-1, -1)) {
          canvas.drawLine(
            path[i] + offset,
            path[i + 1] + offset,
            currentPaint,
          );
        } else if (path[i] != Offset(-1, -1) && path[i + 1] == Offset(-1, -1)) {
          canvas.drawPoints(
            ui.PointMode.points,
            [path[i] + offset],
            currentPaint,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/8eeadd8028c373df87f3a47bd4a35e36

Comment: i did it with both of the method using endrecording and global key method but when the image is generated it not capture the area out side of the screen display area